# Strange: MySQL Left Join, "unknown column"; the same leftjoin doesn't work in multiple-table query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, left-join

I'm trying to run a select query, which is the following:

```
SELECT * FROM pages, c_item_category cc
LEFT JOIN pages_tr ON (pages.page_id = pages_tr.page_id AND lang_id = 2)
LEFT JOIN users ON (pages.page_author = users.u_id)
WHERE (pages.page_id = cc.item_id AND cc.cat_id = 7)
  AND (page_date >= 1317420000 AND page_date <= 1320101999)
  AND (page_showinfos = 1)
ORDER BY page_date ASC LIMIT 0,10
```

But I get this error: Unknown column 'pages.page_id' in 'on clause'

Why is that? I can confirm that I have a column named 'page_id' in 'pages' :)

But, when I do a single-table query with the same left joins, it works well:

```
SELECT * FROM pages
LEFT JOIN pages_tr ON (pages.page_id = pages_tr.page_id AND lang_id = 2)
LEFT JOIN users ON (pages.page_author = users.u_id)
WHERE (page_date >= 1317420000 AND page_date <= 1320101999)
  AND (page_showinfos = 1)
ORDER BY page_date ASC LIMIT 0,10
```

What is my mistake in the first query? :\

Comment: You're trying to combine implicit join and explicit join.  I don't know if MySQL supports that, but I would re-write it as a one or the other.

Comment: MySQL supports it, but the explicit LEFT JOIN has higher priority than the comma, so MySQL joins only `cc` to `pages_tr`, and not the cross-join of `pages` and `cc`. So actually `pages` is an unknown name in itself for that part of the query, not just the `page_id` column. Indeed, you should rewrite it to use a standard `JOIN` instead of the `WHERE`-pseudo-join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it this way instead.

```
SELECT *
FROM pages
LEFT JOIN pages_tr ON (pages.page_id = pages_tr.page_id AND lang_id = 2)
LEFT JOIN users ON (pages.page_author = users.u_id),
c_item_category cc
WHERE (pages.page_id = cc.item_id AND cc.cat_id = 7)
  AND (page_date >= 1317420000 AND page_date <= 1320101999)
  AND (page_showinfos = 1)
ORDER BY page_date ASC LIMIT 0,10
```

Comment: Thank you, should have known this :)